# BQ Sql code to find the count of unique users who used all the devices used by this user but before him

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, window-functions

Suppose I have a table in bigquery containing

userId, deviceId, ds (date partition)

where ds is the date filter

Now everyday data comes in this table, even if device ID has not changed for a user. Due to some irregularities, sometimes it may miss to come which is fine.sometimes deviceId can be NULL also.

What i want to calculate is that for every user, for all the unique devices they have used in past 6 months (compared to current date), how many of those devices were also used by any other user (but strictly before this guys used the device) in past 12 months period.

So lets say, today is 1st December, user A used device 1 from 1st june to 1st august, and device 2 from 1st september to 1st november.now if user B used device 1 from 1st may to 31st may and user C used device 1 from 2nd august to 1st september. Also device 2 wasn't used by any other user. Sp the count is 1 as only 1 user used the device used by User A in last 6 months, before he used it . Note, so I want a single row for each user. We can consider all user present in today's parition for whom we need the rows.

note: last 6 months window is used to find out all the devices used by current row''s user and then we want use last 1 year data to find other user for all his devices before he used it.

I tried window functions, subquery and even array agg. Unable to figure out the logic. Also since the data size is massively huge, i want a extremely optimized solution

Answer (score 0):

I have prepared some sample data from the description you have provided (although it would be better if you provide it so that we know how data looks like). On top of the sample data I have written below query to fetch the number of previous users within 1 year period and before the device is used by current user. I know there would be a lot of corner cases that might not be covered in this query but as per the description this should suffice. This might be a starting point for you for the logic to apply on the entire data.

```
with base as (
select 'a' as user, '1' as device, '2023-06-01' as date_
union all
select 'a' as user, '1' as device, '2023-08-01' as date_
union all
select 'a' as user, '2' as device, '2023-09-01' as date_
union all
select 'a' as user, '2' as device, '2023-11-01' as date_
union all
select 'b' as user, '1' as device, '2023-05-01' as date_
union all
select 'b' as user, '1' as device, '2023-05-31' as date_
union all
select 'x' as user, '1' as device, '2022-11-01' as date_
union all
select 'x' as user, '1' as device, '2022-12-31' as date_
union all
select 'y' as user, '1' as device, '2022-10-01' as date_
union all
select 'y' as user, '1' as device, '2022-11-30' as date_
union all
select 'c' as user, '1' as device, '2023-08-02' as date_
union all
select 'c' as user, '1' as device, '2023-09-01' as date_
),base_agg AS (
  SELECT
    user,
    device,
    MIN(date_) AS device_usage_start,
    MAX(date_) device_usage_end
  FROM
    base
  GROUP BY
    1,
    2)
,curr_prev_data as(SELECT
  a.user AS current_user,
  a.device AS curr_device,
  a.device_usage_start AS curr_user_start_date,
  a.device_usage_end AS curr_user_end_date,
  b.user AS prev_user,
  b.device AS prev_device,
  b.device_usage_start AS prev_start,
  b.device_usage_end AS prev_end
FROM
  base_agg a
LEFT JOIN
  base_agg b
ON
  a.device = b.device
  AND PARSE_DATE('%Y-%m-%d',b.device_usage_end) < PARSE_DATE('%Y-%m-%d',a.device_usage_start) -- previous user
  AND PARSE_DATE('%Y-%m-%d',b.device_usage_end) BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(),INTERVAL 12 month) AND DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(),INTERVAL 6 month) -- WITHIN 6-12 months
)
select 
current_user,
curr_device,
curr_user_start_date,
curr_user_end_date,
count(prev_user) as total_previous_users_in_lastyear
from curr_prev_data
group by 1,2,3,4
```

Below is the output from the query. e.g. As you can see the device 1 was used by 2 users (x & y) prior to user a in month of Oct2022 and Nov2022.
[image: output from the query]